# How to pass arguments in SaveLog Function in Lightning experience

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning, opencti

```
sforce.opencti.saveLog({
                        value: {
                            entityApiName: 'Task',
                            param: param
                        },
                        callback: saveLogCallback
});
```

I am not aware how to pass the param.

I have to pass this type of  values like this:

```
Status : 'Completed',
Type : 'Call',,
CallType : 'Inbound',,
Activitydate : '2016-12-2',,
CallObject : '1705300187',,
CallDurationInSeconds : '45',,
subject : 'Call at 12:29:12 on 2 Dec 2016',
description : 'This is for the call logs testing.'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Place of param you can capture these values in variables and pass them as argument parameters. e.g-

CallType : Calltype,
Activitydate : duedate,
CallObject : callid,,
CallDurationInSeconds : callduration,
subject : subjectstring,
description : descriptionstring

sforce.opencti.saveLog({value: {entityApiName: 'Task',Status : 'Completed',Type :'Call',CallType :Calltype,Activitydate :duedate ,CallObject : callid,CallDurationInSeconds : callduration,Subject : subjectstring,description : descriptionstring},callback: saveLogCallback
});

Answer (score 0):

As Raj Prasad  said, you will need to substitute params with your own params. Your call will be formatted as:

```
sforce.opencti.saveLog({
    value: {
        entityApiName: 'Task',
        Status : 'Completed',
        Type : 'Call',
        CallType : 'Inbound',
        Activitydate : '2016-12-2',
        CallObject : '1705300187',
        CallDurationInSeconds : '45',
        subject : 'Call at 12:29:12 on 2 Dec 2016',
        description : 'This is for the call logs testing.'
    },
    callback: saveLogCallback
});
```

This call will create a new Task. If you want to update an already created task, you will have to pass the Id as parameter too

```
        Id: '00Txxxxxxxxxxxx',
```